# Can't boot after resizing/creating a partition

Tags: boot

I resized a partition and created a new one, with gparted on a ubuntu installation cd, to host LFS.
When i rebooted, the installation would stop in a purple screen and go no further.
After looking for possible solutions I found a work-around that lets me boot to ubuntu. I open a shell in advanced options during boot mode, and write: "mount -o remount,rw /"
This lets me get to ubuntu, but it is lost on reboot.
I used boot-repair but the problem persists.
Below is log from boot-repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rPTgGBCbYk/

I'm running ubuntu 16.04

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is not helping. `sda2 is 97 % full`  best to houseclean or updates will fail.  And your fstab does not show the mount of a / partition? But then I do not know how you are about to boot unless your manual entry is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to update GRUB first.**

Boot into repair mode if you can :

Use the following command :

```
update-grub
```

If it still dont work :

**Fixing reboot/shutdown freezes**

If your machine freezes upon attempts to shutdown or reboot, try modifying /etc/default/grub. Open the file with gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub (graphical interface) or sudo nano /etc/default/grub (command-line). Any other plaintext editor (Vim, Emacs, Kate, Leafpad) is fine too. Find the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add reboot=bios to the end.

If done properly it should result in something like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"

Then save the file, run sudo update-grub and reboot in any way that's possible for you. After that, reboots and shutdowns should start working properly.

With certain hardware (notably DELL) the kernel parameter that you add needs to be reboot=pci (instead of reboot=bios), the procedure remains the same.

- Edit *

To Reinstall the bootloader use :

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sda
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help  but the problem persists. I updated grub and changed the file, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: ` sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sda `

Comment: I get the following error message: "grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory"